# Codeigniter parameters

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I've read the URI parameters user guide and still have a question:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

With the following:
{http://myapp/locations/1}  I get a 404 error...
{http://myapp/locations}   appropriately executes the index() function in the Main controller
{http://myapp/locations/main/locations/1} works, and the value is passed properly to index($var)

I do have other functions in Main.

How is it possible to get the first line to work in order to clean URL's?

Thanks in advance,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

`CodeIgniter` reads an url as `domain/controller_name/method-name/method_parameters` and in your first url here `http://myapp/locations/1` the first portion (myapp) is your domain name, second (locations) is your controller name and the third portion should be controller's method name and in this case you've passed `1` and obviously there's no such a method name, so it's showing error.

if you pass `domain/controller_name` like you did here in this url `http://myapp/locations`, then CodeIgniter reads the first portion as the `domain_name` and the second portion as `controller_name` and when there is no third portion in the url then CodeIgniter calls the `index` method/function by default, so your second url is working.

In your last url you have `http://myapp/locations/main/locations/1` and it's been read as

`myapp`-domain name

`locations`-controller name

`main`-method/function name

and rest of all are passed as `main` controller's arguments. So remember that, the third part of an url is `method/function` name and if third part is not given then `CodeIgniter` calls the `index` method by default and in that case you have to declare a default `index` method/function in that controller, otherwise an error will be occured.